# Is there a way to record when (and how often) Transporters get within a certain distance of each other?

Tags: anylogic

I have an AnyLogic simulation model using trucks and forklifts as agents (Transporter type), and among other things would like to identify each time one of them becomes within a certain distance of another one (example within 5 meters). I will record this count as a variable within the main space of the model. I am using path-guided navigation.
I have seen a method "agentsInRange" which will probably be able to do the trick, but am not sure where to call this from. I assume I should be able to use the AL functionality of "Min distance to obstacle" (TransporterFleet) and "Collision detection timeout" (TransporterControl)?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there don't seem to be pre-built functions for this, afaik, the easiest way is to:

1. add an int variable to your transporter agent type `counter`
2. add an event to your transporter type `checkCollision` that triggers every second or so
3. in the event, loop across the entire population of transporters and count the number that are closer than X meters (use `distanceTo(otherTransporter)` and write your own custom code)
4. add that number to `counter`

Note that this might be very inefficient computationally as it is quite brute-force. But might be good enough :)