# Count the times a transporter is blocked by another transporter

Tags: simulation, block, anylogic

If you have two different transporter types in your model. And you want to have a variable that counts the amount of time they are close to each other (say within 0.5meter) and blocking each other. Is there a way in anylogic to code this?

So that you can say during a day the transport type is 300 times blocked by another transporter type?

I've no clue how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: This is almost an exact duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64428058](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64428058) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69971364](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69971364). The latter of these is a more usefully worded and answered question (although I would say that since I answered it :-)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are no other answers here is a potential solution, which might be very resource-intensive, but it will at least give you something to work with.

You can write an event that records the distance to any other transporter if the distance is less than a specific value.

You can then post-process this by analyzing the events and checking that if it  was closer than the threshold for more than 2 seconds you assume it was being blocked

[image]